# GA4 - Bigquery. Is it possible to have a the same combination of ga_session_id + user_pseudo_id within multiple devices/browsers?

Tags: google-bigquery, session-cookies, google-analytics-4

So, basically I'm trying to count sessions as Google Documentation says the unique session identifier should be a combination of ga_session_id + user_pseudo_id.

But as I can see in the that it happens that the same user_pseudo_id is shared for multiple devices/browsers.

Is it actually the same user?

[BigQuery Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOvQ6.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the same user_pseudo_id can be associated with multiple devices or browsers, indicating the same user across those devices or browsers.

user_pseudo_id connects sessions from the same user across devices or browsers, and the ga_session_id uniquely identifies a session within a device or browser.

Typically, if the ga_session_id matches as well as the user_pseudo_id in different events, this signifies a continuation of the same session across multiple devices or browsers.

Check the timestamp and verify if the events are within 30 minutes of being final.

[https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/Why-does-the-same-user-pseudo-id-appear-across-multiple-devices/m-p/687913#:~:text=Firebase%20Authentication%20Linking%3A%20If%20your,devices%20based%20on%20their%20account](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/Why-does-the-same-user-pseudo-id-appear-across-multiple-devices/m-p/687913#:%7E:text=Firebase%20Authentication%20Linking%3A%20If%20your,devices%20based%20on%20their%20account) is the resources I based the answer off of.